# Error converting to pdf from html using itextpdf (pdfhtml)

Tags: java, itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I have a HTML file containing scripts, images and charts (uses 'svg'). As per one of the iText examples I am using following code to convert input html file into a pdf file:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), new FileOutputStream(dest));
```

During conversion I get following errors:

```
c.i.h.a.i.DefaultHtmlProcessor - No worker found for tag script

c.i.s.r.f.DefaultSvgNodeRendererFactory - Could not find implementation for tag tspan

c.i.h.c.a.u.PaddingApplierUtil - Padding value in percents not supported
```

How do I resolve these errors ?

Comment: Do you get a usable output?  Is it at all what you want?  It may be that these are really just warnings that point out some things that the converter can't deal with, either because of its own limitations, or because of problems in the HTML itself.

It might be hard for anyone to help you much if you can't provide the input HTML.

Comment: I did get the output pdf though it is quite distorted. Tables are rendered fine. Fonts aren't because I didn't set the base path yet. I am also uploading the file here. This is a warning:
`2019-03-13 10:20:44,728 [warn] c.i.s.r.f.DefaultSvgNodeRendererFactory - Could not find implementation for tag tspan`

Comment: [Link to HTML file]
https://jsfiddle.net/nkmittal/3h04wjok/2/

Comment: I also get following error:
2019-03-13 13:05:08,533 [error] c.i.s.r.r.ResourceResolver - Unable to retrieve stream with given base URI (file:/Users/sandbox/app/) and source path (/assets/stylesheets/fonts/lineto-circular-bookitalic.woff)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /assets/stylesheets/fonts/lineto-circular-bookitalic.woff (No such file or directory)
The base URI and source path (in input html is correct).

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: `libraryDependencies += "com.itextpdf" % "kernel" % "7.1.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.itextpdf" % "html2pdf" % "2.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.itextpdf" % "itext-licensekey" % "3.0.4"`

Comment: For your reference I am including two output files (ref Google drive link). template_ext.html is the input file. template_ext_itext.pdf is the output using itext html2pdf code. template_ext_sejda.pdf is the output from REST API call made to "https://api.sejda.com/v1/tasks". The JSON data passed to Sejda API is:

`"type" -> "htmlToPdf",
"htmlCode" -> content,
"pageSize" -> "a4",
"pageOrientation" -> "portrait"`
`
`
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hjKhjc8zWKIxOK4OPv2AnF46z4QJaYJZ?usp=sharing`

Comment: Hello Folks,
Any update on this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: @NKM I don't see any code in the provided google-drive folder. Could you update it please?

Comment: This error is frustrating I have no idea to fix this